# Paging issue mvc .Index not in sync with pagenumber

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Wondering where you can spot and correct what I am doing wrong.
I need to implement some pagination and the issue I have is that the Index is out of synch with the page

EG Pressing on link "2" page2 I get data associated with page3 (21-30)etc...

```
Current Result
1  (1-10)   correct
2  (21-30)  wrong
3  (31-40)  wrong
4  (41-50)  wrong
    etc...

Wanted Result

1 (1-10) 
2  (2-20)
3) (21-30)
4  (31-40)
    etc...
```

I have put a simple sample together

Model

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Items { get; set; }
    public Pager Pager { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        var allProducts = GetProducts();

        int pageIndex;
        if (page <= 1)
        {
            pageIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            pageIndex = page ?? 0;
        }

        int itemsXPage = 10;

        var paginatedProducts = allProducts.Skip(pageIndex * itemsXPage).Take(itemsXPage);

        var pager = Pager
           .Items(allProducts.Count())
           .PerPage(10)
           .Move(page ?? 0)
           .Segment(5)
           .Center();

        var viewModel = new ProductViewModel
        {
            Items = paginatedProducts,
            Pager = pager
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 150; i++)
        {
            var product = new Product { Name = "Product" + i, Category = "Shoes" };
            products.Add(product);
        }
        return products;
    }
```

Pager

```
     link http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/pager-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx

     public  class Pager : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        private int _numberOfPages;
        private int _skipPages;
        private int _takePages;
        private int _currentPageIndex;
        private int _itemsPerPage;

        private Pager()
        {
        }

        private Pager(Pager pager)
        {
            NumberOfItems = pager.NumberOfItems;
            _currentPageIndex = pager._currentPageIndex;
            _numberOfPages = pager._numberOfPages;
            _takePages = pager._takePages;
            _skipPages = pager._skipPages;
            _itemsPerPage = pager._itemsPerPage;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a pager for the given number of items.
        /// </summary>
        public static Pager Items(int numberOfItems)
        {
            return new Pager
            {
                NumberOfItems = numberOfItems,
                _currentPageIndex = 0,
                _numberOfPages = 1,
                _skipPages = 0,
                _takePages = 1,
                _itemsPerPage = numberOfItems
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specifies the number of items per page.
        /// </summary>
        public Pager PerPage(int itemsPerPage)
        {
            int numberOfPages = (NumberOfItems + itemsPerPage - 1) / itemsPerPage;

            return new Pager(this)
            {
                _numberOfPages = numberOfPages,
                _skipPages = 0,
                _takePages = numberOfPages - _currentPageIndex + 1,
                _itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Moves the pager to the given page index
        /// </summary>
        public Pager Move(int pageIndex)
        {
            return new Pager(this)
            {
                _currentPageIndex = pageIndex
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Segments the pager so that it will display a maximum number of pages.
        /// </summary>
        public Pager Segment(int maximum)
        {
            int count = Math.Min(_numberOfPages, maximum);

            return new Pager(this)
            {
                _takePages = count,
                _skipPages = Math.Min(_skipPages, _numberOfPages - count),
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Centers the segment around the current page
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Pager Center()
        {
            int radius = ((_takePages + 1) / 2);

            return new Pager(this)
            {
                _skipPages = Math.Min(Math.Max(_currentPageIndex - radius, 0), _numberOfPages - _takePages)
            };
        }

        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(_skipPages + 1, _takePages).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public bool IsPaged { get { return NumberOfItems > _itemsPerPage; } }

        public int NumberOfPages { get { return _numberOfPages; } }

        public bool IsUnpaged { get { return _numberOfPages == 1; } }

        public int CurrentPageIndex { get { return _currentPageIndex; } }

        public int NextPageIndex { get { return _currentPageIndex + 1; } }

        public int LastPageIndex { get { return _numberOfPages; } }

        public int FirstPageIndex { get { return 1; } }

        public bool HasNextPage { get { return _currentPageIndex < _numberOfPages && _numberOfPages > 1; } }

        public bool HasPreviousPage { get { return _currentPageIndex > 1 && _numberOfPages > 1; } }

        public int PreviousPageIndex { get { return _currentPageIndex - 1; } }

        public bool IsSegmented { get { return _skipPages > 0 || _skipPages + 1 + _takePages < _numberOfPages; } }

        public bool IsEmpty { get { return _numberOfPages < 1; } }

        public bool IsFirstSegment { get { return _skipPages == 0; } }

        public bool IsLastSegment { get { return _skipPages + 1 + _takePages >= _numberOfPages; } }

        public int ItemStart { get { return CurrentPageIndex * _itemsPerPage + 1; } }

        public int ItemEnd
        {
            get { return Math.Min(CurrentPageIndex * _itemsPerPage + _itemsPerPage, NumberOfItems); }
        }

        public int NumberOfItems { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
    @model TestPagingWeb.ViewModels.ProductViewModel
    @{

        foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <li>@item.Name</li>
        }

        <br/>
        @String.Format("Displaying {0} - {1} of {2}",
                                          Model.Pager.ItemStart,
                                          Model.Pager.ItemEnd,
                                          Model.Pager.NumberOfItems);
        <br/>


    if (Model.Pager.HasPreviousPage)
    {
            @Html.ActionLink("<", "Index", new { page = Model.Pager.PreviousPageIndex });
        }

        foreach (int page in Model.Pager)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(page.ToString(), "Index", new { page })
        }

        if (Model.Pager.HasNextPage)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(">", "Index", new { page = Model.Pager.NextPageIndex });
        }
    }
```

Can you spot what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong

```
if (page <= 1)
    {
        pageIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        pageIndex = page ?? 0;
    }
```

just decrement you page number instead of this, it seems you page var is 1 based but the index is 0 based.

As is you have 1 coming in for page one which gets the page index of 0, but if you pass in 2 it stays at 2 so there is no way to get the actual pageindex of 1

Comment: Thanks for your reply ."just decrement you page number instead of this, it seems you page var is 1 based but the index is 0 based."  that is correct. could you show me what you mean? I have tried all sort of solutions

Comment: Instead of the code block above you should just do pageIndex = page - 1; then if pageindex < 0 throw.

Comment: thanks that did the trick however my text displaying .... of 149 is wrong.Is it too much too ask if these formulas are wrong 
        public int ItemStart { get { return CurrentPageIndex * _itemsPerPage + 1; } }

        public int ItemEnd {get { return Math.Min(CurrentPageIndex * _itemsPerPage + _itemsPerPage, NumberOfItems); }}